# bootstrap one page theme not working with embed video while full screen using iframe

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a one page bootstrap theme, problem is that, I embed vimeo video when I click full screen button then screen going to full but not whole screen, this let some right side

Comment: We are definitely going to need some more info than this. Please include code examples.

Comment: You need to provide more information, but from what I can see, you should try to avoid using iframe

Comment: Include some examples if you are hesitant to give your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not an issue with Bootstrap (or the theme), but with how you embed the video from Vimeo.

By default Vimeo doesn't allow fullscreen (this due browser limitations in Webkit and Mozilla).
To fix this, use the following embed code:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

*source: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding*

Comment: I found my problem, my problem with animation.css, please tell me how to to remove animation in this div.

Comment: <div class="col-md-14 col-sm-14">
                                
                                <div class="member-item">
                               
                                    <div class="thumb">
                                   
                                    <div class='videoWrapper'>
                             
                                   <iframe style="overflow:hidden" src="<?=$row['link']?>" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>